# Compare two sheets and show a summary with only rows where a specific column has changed for that primary key, without altering source data

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, vlookup

I'm trying to generate a report that will regularly compare current raw data with that of previous reporting period and **only** show rows (primary keys) where a certain column's value has changed between the two, or where a row is present in one spreadsheet and not the other.

The raw data will be placed in two separate worksheets within the file, for example as follows:

(Note: The values may be in any order and are not sequential, and there will be other columns present that are irrelevant to the example/summary)

Worksheet 1 (old data):

| Primary key | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 4 |
| E | 5 |

Worksheet 2 (current data):

| Primary key | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 100 |
| D | 4 |
| F | 6 |
| C | 3 |

I'm looking for a solution that will provide the below result in a seperate summary sheet **without** editing/adding to the data worksheets at all.

Intended result (in separate worksheet, but same file):

| Primary key | Old value | New value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 2 | 100 |
| E | 5 | Not Found |
| F | Not Found | 6 |

In the above example, the information pertaining to B is included as the value has changed. E and F are included as they are present in one sheet and not the other. A, C, and D are not present in the output as they are present in both and contain the same value for each of those keys.

Also worth noting: this output is not the final product. The keys/values in this output sheet will need to be referenceable for other calculations, etc. in yet more sheets.

Comment: What type of solution are you looking for, formula, vba, power query? What have your tried so far? Without this, your question will probably be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @gns100 I'm open to any solutions that will work, however I expect that using VBA would be disallowed in my work environment. I expect that there is some solution that could be done using vlookup/pivot table combinations, but I'm not certain or else I would have been more specifc.

Comment: To get to your intended table, I would use a formula like `sort(unique(primary1, primary2)` then for columns Old value and new value you would just do `xlookups()`. If you only want changes then it will be more complex (probably dropping those formulas mentioned above into a makearray and wrapping that with a filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the latest version of Excel, you can combine UNIQUE, FILTER, VSTACK functions to get the primary keys that are different or not exist in one of the columns. As an example:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(UNIQUE(VSTACK(A3:B7,D3:E7),FALSE,TRUE),{1,0}))
```

You can also use this formula that uses CHOOSECOLS fnction:

```
=UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(VSTACK(A3:B7,D3:E7),FALSE,TRUE),1))
```

[image]

You can then use INDEX MATCH functions to find old and new values. To find old values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$7,MATCH(A11,$A$3:$A$7,0)),"Not found")
```

To find new values:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$7,MATCH(A11,$D$3:$D$7,0)),"Not found")
```

Drag down the formulae to fill the cells.

[image]
[image]